# Trouble With Proving a Remark of Hatcher's Regarding Characteristic Maps of CW Complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

In the third paragraph on pg. 7 of [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) there is the definition of characteristic maps of a CW complex (the definition of a CW complex can be found on pg. 5.)

Just after defining a characteristic maps, Hatcher writes:

> The restriction of a characteristic map $\Phi_{\alpha}:D^n_\alpha\to X$ to the interior of $D^n_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism onto $e^n_\alpha$ (where $e^n_\alpha$ is the image of $\text{Int}(D^n_\alpha)$ under $\Phi_\alpha$).

In, other words, the restriction of $\Phi_\alpha$ to the interior of $D^n_\alpha$ is an embedding.

I was able to prove this by assuming additionally that $X$ is Hausdorff.
Here is the argument I have:

> **Lemma.** Let $B^n$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbf R^n$.
>   Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $f:D^n\to X$ be a continuous map such that
>   i) $f$ is injective on $B^n$, and
>   ii) $f(S^{n-1})\cap f(B^n)$ is empty.
>   Then $f|_{B^n}:B^n\to X$ is a topological embedding.

*Proof.* Without loss of generality we may assume that $f$ is surjective.
We have the following diagram:

[image]

where by $D^n/f$ we mean the quotient space of $D^n$ formed by the fibres of $f$.
We need to show that $f|_{B^n}:B^n\to X$ is an embedding.
Since $f$ is a surjective continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, we know that $f$ is a quotient map.
Therefore $\bar f$ is a homeomorphism.
In the light of this, it suffices to prove that $\pi|_{B^n}:B^n\to \pi(B^n)$ is a homeomorphism.
To this end, note that since $f$ is injective on $B^n$, we have $\pi|_{B^n}:B^n\to \pi(B^n)$ is bijective.
So all that remains to show is that $\pi|_{B^n}$ is an open map.

To this end, let $U$ be open in $B^n$.
We claim that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=U$.
One containment is obvious.
For the reverse containment let $x\in \pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$.
Then $\pi(x)\in \pi(U)$, and thus $\bar f\circ \pi\in \bar f\circ \pi(B^n)$, giving $f(x)\in f(B^n)$.
Using (ii) here leads to the conclusion that $x\in B^n$.
But since $f$ is injective on $B^n$, we further deduce that $x\in U$.
So we have $U=\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$.

From this we infer that $\pi(U)$ is open in $D^n/f$ and is therefore open in $\pi(B^n)$ too.

**Remark.** The condition (ii) is necessary in the hypothesis of the above proposition for result to hold.
For otherwise we have the figure-eight curve is would serve as a counterexample.

It is clear that a characteristic map satisfies the hypothesis of the above lemma and thus given an embedding when restricted to the interior of the disc.

> **Question.** How do we prove that the restriction of a characteristic map to the interior of the disc is an embedding without assuming that $X$ is a Hausdorff space.

Comment: CW complexes are Hausdorff. I don't know a reference, but here's how I would go about writing down a proof. First, find a proof that a CW complex $X$ is locally contractible: every $x \in X$ has a neighborhood basis of contractible open subsets. It's a pretty concrete construction, building each neighborhood up inductively as the union of its intersections with the skeleta. Adapt that proof: using the details of the construction, check that if $x \ne y$ then there exist disjoint members $U_x,U_y$ of their neighborhood bases. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following general fact

Assume $X$ is space, and $f:A\to Y$ is a map from the subspace $A$ of $X$ to a space $Y$. We have the following pushout square.

[image]

Then if $A$ is closed (open) in $X$, the restriction $g:X\setminus A \to Z$ of $F$ is a closed (open) embedding.

You already gave a proof for the case that $A$ is closed (by replacing the pair ($D^n,S^{n-1})$  in your proof with a general $(X,A)$), and for the case of an open $A$ simply switch the terms *open* and *closed* in the proof.

Now the $n$-skeleton $X^n$ is constructed as a pushout

[image]

where $\varphi$ is the union of all attaching maps $\varphi_\alpha$. Since $\coprod S_\alpha^{n-1}$ is closed in $\coprod D_\alpha^n$, it follows that $\Phi$ restricts on each open ball $B_\alpha^n$ to an embedding.